# double precision to numeric with 2 decimal points in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query of postgreSQL in data like:

```
SELECT 
(e + u) * 100::double precision / (se + su + OLF) AS "Sample"
FROM lfs_dept,
    lfs_dept_final sm
  WHERE n = sn;
```

How can i make the result as numeric rounded to 2 decimal point ?

Comment: YOur code is not standard SQL.  Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: and please include table structures with data examples

Comment: Do you need bankers rounding or standard rounding?

Comment: @GordonLinoff   it is postgrasql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most databases support `round()`:

```
SELECT ROUND( (e + u) * 100::double precision / (se + su + OLF), 2) AS "Sample"
FROM lfs_dept JOIN
     lfs_dept_final sm
     ON n = sn;
```

Note:  I also fixed your syntax so it uses `JOIN`.  You should qualify all column references so it is clear what tables they come from.